# LINQ C# Creating Dictionary of Dictionaries using GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I can't seem to find a solution to this, and the error message is not very helpful.

I have a DataTable:

iGuid, iDateTime, iDecimal

I want to create a Dictionary of Dictionaries, such that...

iGuid -> iDateTime -> iDecimal.

For example.

```
Guid1, Monday, 4
Guid1, Tuesday, 4
Guid1, Friday, 1
Guid2, Monday, 1
Guid2, Tuesday, 1
```

Now I want this to be made into a dictionary with the key of iGuid, and the value another Dictionary with the key of iDateTime, and the value of iDecimal.

My code right now is:

```
Dictionary<Guid, Dictionary<DateTime, decimal>> val = iDataTable.OfType<CustomDataRow>().GroupBy(r => new { r.iGuid } )
    .ToDictionary<Guid, Dictionary<DateTime, decimal>>( row => row.Key.iGuid,
             child => child.ToDictionary<DateTime, decimal>(subKey => subKey.iDateTime, subVal => subVal.iDecimal));
```

I have to return this typed, as I need to use it in other functions (If I throw a var in front of it, it's fine).

Comment: maybe unrelated, but your last statement doesn't make sense.  If you use `var`, it's still strongly typed.  What you're seeing is that your expression compiles, just not into the type you're wanting/expecting.

Comment: When you use `var`, what type does the compiler give you? You can hover your mouse over `var` and see the type.

Comment: Please post the error message

Comment: Error message: CustomDataRow does not contain a definition for ToDictionary.

Comment: For other comments, they are anonymous types (But with the correct type inside, which is why I was confused)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is the wrong usage of the method:

```
    public static Dictionary<TKey, TSource> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector
)
```

As you can see the types specified in this call is not the expected return type of the dictionary.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549277(v=vs.100).aspx

Since you are not using the source (CustomDataRow) as the value Type of your dictionary, you cannot use this signature.

This one should do the job:

```
Dictionary<Guid, Dictionary<DateTime, decimal>> val = 
    iDataTable
    .OfType<CustomDataRow>()
    .GroupBy(r => r.iGuid)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, 
                  group => group.ToDictionary(dataRow => dataRow.iDateTime, 
                                              dataRow => dataRow.iDecimal));
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why this works and mine above does not? The major difference I see is that you're not adding the types to the ToDictionary's, I've tried this without the group.Key.iGuid and it didn't fix it.  Why does not typing the ToDictionary fix the problem?

Comment: Dictionary signature with type is NOT the return type of the dictionary.

Comment: Edited answer to explain a little better your issue